# init db error and postgresql not found after brew install postgresql

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew

command I am trying to execute:

`pg_ctl init -D <path-to-db>`

The error its giving me:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "aashishgangwani".
This user must also own the server process.

initdb: error: file "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq/13.3/share/postgresql/postgres.bki" does not exist
This might mean you have a corrupted installation or identified
the wrong directory with the invocation option -L.
pg_ctl: database system initialization failed
```

When trying "which postgresql" and "where postgresql" it gives "not found" over here:

```
(base) aashishgangwani@Aashishs-MacBook-Pro ~ % which postgresql
postgresql not found
(base) aashishgangwani@Aashishs-MacBook-Pro ~ % where postgresql
postgresql not found
```

Update: I have tried doing `brew reinstall postgres` it doesn't work

Comment: On a normal install there is no executable named "postgresql", so its absence from your PATH is unrelated to your problem.  Is there a file named 'postgres.bki' anywhere on your system?

Comment: @jjanes Yes I did find it in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql/13.3/share/postgresql/postgres.bki and then I copy pasted the whole postgres folder into the libpq directory(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq/13.3/share/) so things are working fine for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I did some debugging and found out that I may need several files of postgres into libq share folder(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq/13.3/share/) so I copy pasted the whole postgres directory(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql/13.3/share/postgresql) into the libq share folder(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq/13.3/share/) and `pg_ctl init -D <path-to-db>`
is working fine for me now.